# Excel App & read-only SPO folder

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, excel

We have a strange behaviour of excel with files on SharePoint. The situation is as following:

- User has read-only rights on SharePoint
- Folder (also read-only) contains Excel file
- Excel file is set to edit rights for user via "grant access"

Editing the Excel file in the browser works as Excel Online respects the individual permissions on the file.
Excel Desktop app refuses to save the file because "the folder is write protected".

Does Excel Desktop not recognize the individual permissions on a file or why is this error happening?

Answer (score 0):

I test in my environment, but I can save my files successfully.

1.Are other users with same permissions facing the same problem? View through another computer or account.

2.Whether all SharePoint libraries have the same problem? You could create a new SharePoint library to check.

3.Check if the same issue occurs with other Excel files.

4.Try to use a different browser or your browser's InPrivate mode to see if the same error occurs.

5.You can try turning on autosave and then opening the file on Online again to see if the update was saved.
[image]